# Single LDAP configuration for login module and application use

Tags: java, jboss, ldap

I am developing a JavaEE application that needs to access a LDAP server. The access to the LDAP server is used to authenticate users at the login page AND in some features inside the application (custom searchs and listings).

For the authentication part, I am using JAAS so I can use the basic LDAP login module, with its own configuration, or a custom login module. But I don't want to configure the LDAP parameters twice, one in the standalone.xml for the login module, and one inside the application (properties file, or in a table in the database) to be able to use it to implement the required features. The ideal case would be to configure only once in the standalone.xml file and use that configuration for both the login module and the application.

Does JBoss (EAP 6) have some kind of "custom resource" wich can be configured in the standalone.xml and be accessed with JNDI? Is there another solution that allows me to configure only once the LDAP connection parameters, and use that configuration from multiple places?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved it.

What I did is to define a new binding of type external-context: in the standalone.xml file, inside the "urn:jboss:domain:naming" subsystem, I declared the context:

```
<bindings>
  <external-context name="java:global/..." module="org.jboss.as.naming" class="javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext" cache="true">
    <environment>
      <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
      <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://...:389"/>
      <property name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
      <property name="java.naming.security.principal" value="cn=..."/>
      <property name="java.naming.security.credentials" value="..."/>
    </environment>
  </external-context>
</bindings>
```

Then, I can use that context wherever I need:

```
try {
  Context initContext = new InitialContext();
  InitialDirContext ldapContext = (InitialDirContext)initContext.lookup("java:global/...");
  // Connection OK!
}catch(Exception ex) {
  // Connection failure!
}
```

The drawback of this solution is that I can't use the ldap login module included with JBoss, because it does not let me use the context. So, I will have to develop a custom login module.